# Is there any way for a web application to read real time data from a bluetooth enabled hardware? If not, what are the alternatives?

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, bluetooth, phonegap-plugins

so I'm an electrical engineering student with the following problem:
I have a sensor which outputs analog voltage from which I do an ADC using a micro controller. Now I need this  value to be read real time in a web application WIRELESSLY and also store the value in a master database. I have limited knowledge of web based applications but I'm willing to learn. But before that, I need to know if there any way I can achieve this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any alternatives? @SLaks

Answer (score 1):

The browser is very good at make HTTP requests. What you will need t do is write a separate piece of software that communicates directly with your hardware (say a Python or Java application), and provides an HTTP API to query the current state of the hardware.

On the same machine that this software is running, you can launch a browser and point it to your app at say `http://localhost:8080` to display the relevant information.

If you want this to work wirelessly, it's not a big step to have it work with multiple machines on the same wireless network - just replace `localhost` with the machines IP address.

Comment: Thank you for this. It has provided me with something to start. I will work on it and if I come up with more questions, I will let you know. Thanks again!

Comment: `The browser is really only good at make HTTP requests` That's not very true; look at WebRTC, getUserMedia, WebSockets, and many other features.

Comment: Thx @SLaks. Clarified.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you give a try to the experimental [Web Bluetooth API](http://webbluetoothcg.github.io/web-bluetooth/). This Web API, currently being added to Chrome (and more browsers soon), makes it possible for websites to discover and communicate with devices over the Bluetooth 4 wireless standard using GATT.

Check out https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/07/interact-with-ble-devices-on-the-web to learn more about it and have a look at the samples https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/web-bluetooth/

Here's how it could look for instance to read the battery level of your device with nothing but JavaScript:

```js
navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice({ filters: [{ services: ['battery_service'] }] })
.then(device => device.gatt.connect())
.then(server => {
  // Getting Battery Service...
  return server.getPrimaryService('battery_service');
})
.then(service => {
  // Getting Battery Level Characteristic...
  return service.getCharacteristic('battery_level');
})
.then(characteristic => {
  // Reading Battery Level...
  return characteristic.readValue();
})
.then(buffer => {
  var data = new DataView(buffer);
  console.log('Battery percentage is ' + data.getUint8(0));
})
.catch(error => { console.log(error); });
```